# Bash, command as function is not working, but manually is OK

Tags: bash, function

I need save mysql dump from remote machine to file on local, so connect via `ssh` to remote machine, run `mysqldump` on remote machine and save it to file on local, where script is running.

I have 2 bash scripts, `function.sh` and `export-db.sh`, and 1 configuration file `export-db-ssc.cfg`

File `function.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"

date_time="$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")"
date_time_now="date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"
file_name="$(basename "$0")"
file_log="log/${file_name%.*}.log"
email_sender='hosek@email.cz'
email_recipients='hosek@email.cz'

message()
{
    if [ $1 = "i" ]
    then
        echo "`$date_time_now`|sofimon|"$file_name"|$2|info." 2>&1 | tee -a "$file_log"
    elif [ $1 = "t" ]
    then
        echo "`$date_time_now`|sofimon|"$file_name"|$2|true." 2>&1 | tee -a "$file_log"
    else [ $1 = "f" ]
        echo "`$date_time_now`|sofimon|"$file_name"|$2|false!" 2>&1 | tee -a "$file_log"
    fi
}

# $1 = description, $2 = command, $3 = command if $2 is true, $4 = command if $2 is false
doit()
{
    if
        $2
    then
        message "t" "$1"
        "$3"
    else
        message "f" "$1"
        result="false"
        "$4"
    fi
}

email()
{
cat "$file_log" | mail -a "From: sofimon <$email_sender>" -a "Content-type: text/plain" -s "sofimon" -r $email_sender $email_recipients
mv "$file_log" "$file_log"-"$date_time"
rm -rf "$file_log"
}

# Check if run file exists, if so, then exit
if [ -f "$file_log" ]
then
    exit 1
fi

> "$file_log"
```

File `export-db.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

source function.sh

folder_export="/mnt/export"
username="sofimon"
divider=";"

# Read config file, variables as var divided by ;
while IFS=$divider read -ra var; do

    command_mkdir="mkdir -p "$folder_export"/"${var[0]}""
    command_mysqldump="sudo mysqldump -uroot -p"${var[1]}" --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --host=localhost --quote-names --ignore-table=mysql.event --opt --all-databases"
    command_ssh="ssh -i id_rsa_sofimon -n "$username"@"${var[0]}" "$command_mysqldump" > "$folder_export"/"${var[0]}"/"$date_time"-"${var[0]}".mysql"


# Check commands
    echo $command_mkdir
    echo $command_ssh

# Run commands
    doit "create export folder "${var[0]}"" "$command_mkdir"
    doit "dump database from "${var[0]}"" "$command_ssh"

done <<< $(cat "${file_name%.*}"-$1.cfg | grep -v "#")

email
```

File `export-db-ssc.cfg`.

```
# host;password
ssc-osw-web;PASSWORD
```

When I run

`./export-db.sh ssc`

it shows me this.

```
hosek@osw-backup:~/sofimon$ ./export-db.sh ssc
mkdir -p /mnt/export/ssc-osw-web
ssh -n sofimon@ssc-osw-web sudo mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --host=localhost --quote-names --ignore-table=mysql.event --opt --all-databases > /mnt/export/ssc-osw-web/20200221-110536-ssc-osw-web.mysqldump
20200221-110536|sofimon|export-db.sh|create export folder ssc-osw-web|true.
bash: /mnt/export/ssc-osw-web/20200221-110536-ssc-osw-web.mysqldump: No such file or directory
20200221-110538|sofimon|export-db.sh|dump database from ssc-osw-web|false!
```

So `command_mkdir` is OK, but `command_ssh` is not working.

Why error `No such file or directory`?

When I run command `$command_ssh` manually in terminal, it works perfectly.

```
ssh -n sofimon@ssc-osw-web sudo mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --host=localhost --quote-names --ignore-table=mysql.event --opt --all-databases > /mnt/export/ssc-osw-web/20200221-110536-ssc-osw-web.mysqldump
```

Tried to modify script for this result when `echo $command_ssh`.

```
ssh -n sofimon@ssc-osw-web "sudo mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --host=localhost --quote-names --ignore-table=mysql.event --opt --all-databases" > /mnt/export/ssc-osw-web/20200221-110536-ssc-osw-web.mysqldump
```

Same error.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

New code with functions.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"

date_time="$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")"
now="date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"
module="$1"
config="$2"
log="log/${module%.*}.log"
email_sender='hosek@ssc.cas.cz'
email_recipients='hosek@ssc.cas.cz'
#email_recipients='hosek@ssc.cas.cz osi@ssc.cas.cz'


# Declare functions

message()
{
if [ $1 = "i" ]
then
echo "`$now`|sofimon|"$module"|"$config"|$2|info." 2>&1 | tee -a "$log"
elif [ $1 = "t" ]
then
echo "`$now`|sofimon|"$module"|"$config"|$2|true." 2>&1 | tee -a "$log"
else [ $1 = "f" ]
echo "`$now`|sofimon|"$module"|"$config"|$2|false!" 2>&1 | tee -a "$log"
fi
}

doit()
{
#message "i" "$1"
if
"$1"
then
message "t" "$1"
else
message "f" "$1"
result="false"
fi
#message "i" "$1"
}

email()
{
cat "$log" | mail -a "From: sofimon <$email_sender>" -a "Content-type: text/plain" -s "sofimon" -r $email_sender $email_recipients
}

# Declare module functions

export_db()
{
folder_export="/mnt/export"
username="sofimon"
mkdir -p "$folder_export"/"${var[0]}"
ssh -i id_rsa_sofimon -n "$username"@"${var[0]}" "sudo mysqldump -uroot -p"${var[1]}" --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --host=localhost --quote-names --ignore-table=mysql.event --opt --all-databases" > "$folder_export"/"${var[0]}"/"$date_time"-"${var[0]}".mysql
}

# Check if run file exists, if so, then exit

if [ -f "$log" ]
then
message "f" "script is still runnning"
exit 1
else
> "$log"
fi

# Read config file, variables as var divided by ' '

while IFS=' ' read -ra var; do
doit "$module"
done <<< $(cat "${module%.*}"-"$config".cfg | grep -v "#")
#email
mv "$log" "$log"_"$date_time"
rm -rf "$log"
```

But it returns this.

```
hosek@osw-backup:~/sofimon$ ./sofimon.sh export-db ssc
./sofimon.sh: line 34: export-db: command not found
20200224-133436|sofimon|export-db|ssc|export-db|false!
hosek@osw-backup:~/sofimon$
```

Why, if function `export-db` is declared?

Comment: Welcome! Is your `if` statement like shown, or is a typo?

Comment: @guillermochamorro No, it is not typo.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, yes. One more thing, what shebang are you using? Is it `#!/bin/bash` or something else? `source` is not standard or portable.

Comment: That has A LOT of problems, but of course `command_ssh` doesn't work because of the `>` (which has already been explained to death ;-)): Simpler example: `ssh user@host : > file` will create `file` on the __local__ machine, but `ssh='ssh user@host : > file'; $ssh` will create `file` on the __remote__ machine.

Comment: @mosvy I updated `command_ssh`, result is now `ssh -i id_rsa_sofimon -n sofimon@ssc-osw-web "sudo mysqldump -uroot -pPASS --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --host=localhost --quote-names --ignore-table=mysql.event --opt --all-databases" > /mnt/export/ssc-osw-web/20200221-143024-ssc-osw-web.mysql
`. And why it is working when I run this command manually?

Comment: That won't work either. There are a lot answers which explain this at length, but basically: the shell performs its [sequence of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) on the command line in a fixed order ONCE; it does not keep re-scanning the command line and re-expanding it recursively. The simplest example is `cmd='echo foo > file'; $cmd`, which will print `foo > file` without any redirection, not `foo` into `file`. TL;DR you'll have to change your approach and use functions instead command lines in variables.

Comment: In any standard shell, it's trivial to do "symbolic references", I don't get why people try complicated stuff instead of `foo(){ echo foo "$@"; }; bar(){ echo bar; }; ...; func=foo; ... ; "$func" "$@"`.

Comment: @mosvy I don't understand, because manually it is working. What is the best way to modify this script with all his logic? Functions instead variables as you wrote? Some example? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use functions instead of variables, as in that example. Functions can easily call other functions _by name_, Example on top of the previous: `doit(){ "$1" "$2"; }; doit foo 3 ; doit bar`.

Comment: @mosvy I used functions as you wrote, but it doesn't work as I want. Could you look at updated question? Thanks.

Comment: I see no functions ;-) I was thinking of something like: `command_mkdir(){ mkdir -p "$folder_export/${var[0]}"; }; cmd_ssh(){ ... > ...; }` ... `doit(){ if "command_$2"; then ...; }`.

Comment: @mosvy There are functions, which can be started via entered variables, so for example, command is `sofimon export-db ssc`, which means `$1 = export-db (function to run)` and `$2 = ssc (configuration file)`. I want to run function via first parameter `$1`, which will be loaded/chosen in `while` loop, based on this parameter. While loop will execute this command with readind config file line-by-line, divided by `space`, stored to `var[0]`, `var[1]`, etc. Is it clear? :) How can I do this?

Comment: fwiw, you're defining an `export_db` function, but trying to run `export-db` (`_` vs `-`).

Comment: @mosvy :) Oh my god, you are right. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because the command string has the redirection to `/mnt/export/ssc-osw-web/20200221-110536-ssc-osw-web.mysqldump` is being applied on the remote system, whereas you have created the containing directory on the local system.

There is no easy way to fix this with the code you have written, because you cannot* embed a redirection in a variable holding a command string.

<sub>(* I suppose you can with `eval` or by calling `bash -c`, but you *really, really* don't want to go there.)</sub>

Comment: Done, updated in question.